# How to get the IP address of a machine in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address

How do I get the IP address of a machine in C#?

Comment: then you could at least link to the article and tell us what's wrong with it. And what's wrong with loops by the way? :)

Comment: As phrased, "127.0.0.1" is a correct answer. It's an IP address, of the current machine.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm still not sure if `return 127.0.0.1` would be an answer I'd upvote :)

Comment: @hobodave, maybe he just thought it would be a useful question and answer to have on StackOverflow - the more questions and answers there are here the more useful it is, no?

Comment: @ArielBH, I just googled ".net get ip address of current machine" and got this question.  Your comment is less than useless.

Comment: Follow the answer in this link. It works for me. [Stack Overflow Get IP Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669186/ipaddress-of-a-login-system/39524251#39524251)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

Your machine doesn't have a single IP address, and some of the returned addresses can be IPv6.

MSDN links:

- [Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(lightweight).aspx)
- [IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(lightweight).aspx)

Alternatively, as [MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters) mentioned, `127.0.0.1` / `::1` is the [loopback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback_address) and will always refer to the local machine. For obvious reasons, however, it cannot be used to connect to the local machine from a remote machine.

Comment: Copied from @patridge in the other answer: If you are looking for a more relevant IP address, you may want to exclude loopback IPs (e.g., 127.0.0.1 and ::1) with something like this: .Where(ip => !Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip))

Answer (score 10):

My desired answer was

```
string ipAddress = "";
if (Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Length > 0)
{
     ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is executing `GetHostAddresses` and `GetHostName` twice; you should assign the results of GetHostAddresses to a variable and then check the `Length`.

Comment: If you are looking for a more relevant IP address, you may want to exclude loopback IPs (e.g., 127.0.0.1 and ::1) with something like this: `.Where(ip => !Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 IPHostEntry ip = DNS.GetHostByName (strHostName);
 IPAddress [] IPaddr = ip.AddressList;

 for (int i = 0; i < IPaddr.Length; i++)
 {
  Console.WriteLine ("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, IPaddr[i].ToString ());
 }
```

Comment: GetHostByName is deprecated - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostbyname.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST

           // Get the IP
            string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

//use Following Namespace-
using System.Net;

Answer (score 0):

```
NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces(); //get all network interfaces
IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()); // get all IP addresses based on the local host name

foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters) //for each Network interface in addapters
{
    IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties(); // get the ip properties from the adapter and store them into properties
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in properties.UnicastAddresses) // for each UnicastIPAddressInformation in the IPInterfaceProperties Unicast address( this assocaites the IP address with the correct adapter)
    {
        //if the operationalStatus of the adapter is up and the ip Address family is in the Internwork
        if ((adapter.Name == "Ethernet" || adapter.Name == "Ethernet 2") && (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)) //test against the name of the adapter you want to get
        {
            ipAddress = ip.Address.ToString();
                        
        }//end if
    }//end inner for, the UnicastIPAddressInformation for
}
```