# Determine how many users viewed a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, visitor-statistic

I am working on a component in C# to record how many unique viewers have viewed my website / page, making certain the same user revisiting, is not recorded twice. What is an efficient method to write such a component? Do you track cookies or session objects?
Would I record their ip address (which is not static) or computer name?
This information would be stored in a database (as far as I know)

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot get their computer name. It's never sent over the interwebz. You could check if the request with the open connection is the first one with that connection or not. I don't really know ASP.net so I don't know if you can access http-connections' information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) - it's free, extremely easy to implement, provides more statistics than you could ever want, and can provide (as best as it is possible using cookies) unique visitor stats. If you really need to store the data in a database (why?) then you can use the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed) to get at it and do what you want with it.

Comment: +1 for the API link, didn't know Google had one for Analytics.

Comment: where would you store the data, if not the database? I am open to retool. Many thanks for the Google suggestion.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you need to do with the data - but if it's already stored in Google then do you need to replicate that storage locally? Or could you view / manipulate it directly from Google, via the API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can record IP address, if you use a traditional Login scheme (if using membership user) this [Link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/tracking-user-activity.aspx) can guide you. Check this question on [IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019431/how-to-get-ip-address-of-machine-in-c) which tells you how IP can be gathered. It's not a bad idea if you get the [MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c) of the host machine so you can easily determine the unique visitor tracking.

Comment: MAC isn't sent beyond the first router is it?

Answer (score 1):

People are saying that recording IP is a bad idea because you could have situations with hundreds of people behind the same IP, this is true, however, using IP address will still give you a statistically meaningul number.

If it is core for your application to guarantee unique, then unfortunatly that is not possible to do in a guaranteed way.

Answer (score 0):

Recording the IP address is not a good idea as many people actually use NAT to get from their local network to the Internet.  So many people would appear to you as a single person because they all have the same public IP address.  If you are on an intranet, this might work but definitely not for a public web site.

A better solution is to write a GUID to a cookie on the user's computer and stored in your database.  Then look for that cookie again in the future and compare with the values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Unique visits by IP address is always a problem, as you could have an organisation with a unique IP but hundreds of people behind that IP.

I think cookies are your best bet.

I assume you have a reason for not using a stats or analytics package?

Comment: stats or analytics package? Any free ones out there? Other than cost, its the configuration involved (versus developing a component that can be reused)

Comment: Google Analytics? http://www.google.com/analytics/

All it requires is a few lines of Javascript on your pages.

EDIT: You can disregard this I guess, as you updated the original question. Since you need to store your stats in a database an off-the-shelf package may not suit.

Answer (score 0):

Both IP addresses and cookies have their tradeoffs. A single user could be hopping from wifi hotspot to wifi hotspot, throwing off your IP metrics. Many users could be behind the same IP address (employer, ISP, proxy, etc.). So IP address would not be entirely accurate.

On the other hand, a single user at a single IP could access your website through multiple browsers or devices, so cookies would not be entirely accurate.

And what of the user that accesses your website from home and from work? One visitor, two (at minimum) unique cookies *and* IP addresses.

Pick the invalid data that works best for you.