# Finding the IP Address of my system on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, .net, ip-address

I need my system IP address. I've used Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"] but it is being provided IP address of my network(intranet) not my local system ip.

Actually I've set session state off and want to identify the user request. So i want to fetch the system IP not router/network IP.
Please tell me the appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Request.UserHostAddress.
Try this.

Comment: This property  provide the IP address of my router. I want to identify systems in network individually.

Comment: Do you want to get the computer's name?
what about trying this?

Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name

Answer (score 0):

try this

[how to get ip address of machine in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019431/how-to-get-ip-address-of-machine-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]

As seen on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(VS.90).aspx