# How to get internet IP address from C# Windows App

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to get my own IP address in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)
>   [how to get ip address of machine in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019431/how-to-get-ip-address-of-machine-in-c)

Hi all, I am currently developing a c# application for windows using WPF. I would like to get the computers external IP address i.e. the internet address not the local computer ip address or the local router address.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019431/how-to-get-ip-address-of-machine-in-c

Comment: We have a triplicate on our hands unless this question get closed...triplicate...triplicate...

Comment: Note that the answers on those questions tend towards showing ANY ipv4 ip, not the internet address -- which is why I think this shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @NickAldwin I agree the OP wants to know the internet address, whereas the other questions given as duplicates may\probably return a local IP address.

Comment: I guess nobody looks closely at duplicate requests :(

Comment: @NickAldwin Sometimes people don't read the question properly either :)

Comment: @chibacity Very true, that was not intended to be a mean comment, as I am perfectly aware that it might seem hypocritical.

Answer (score 5):

Like stated earlier, you need an external web server. An easy call to HTTP GET with the URL "http://checkip.dyndns.org/" will get you a simple text string with your IP.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]
A simple request to [here](http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp) will get you your ip.

This is a way to get any network address (not necessarily the internet ip) as pointed out in the comments:

```
IPAddress host = IPAddress.None;
foreach (IPAddress ip in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
        host = ip;
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
             break;
    }
```

Comment: This will retrieve the first IPv4 address of the local machine, not necessarily the external address of the machine (not even guaranteed to be a internet accessible interface).

Comment: Your edit answers the question. Remove the old code and you'll get an up vote from me. :)

Comment: @chibacity I left it in so that Simon's comment wouldn't seem strange...and to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a web server sitting somewhere in the cloud so that you can call and that will be able to give you your external IP address.

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c/4484369#4484369) one is free.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found is to do a httpWebRequest to http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp and parse the results for the ip

Comment: They specifically want you to not do that.  See the comment in the web source: `<!--Please set your code to scrape your IP from www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp For more info, please see our "Recommended Automation Practices" thread in the Forum.-->`

Answer (score -1):

You can try connecting to whatismyip.com, as shown in the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DreamInCode.Snippets
{
    public class IpFinder
    {
        public static IPAddress GetExternalIp()
        {
            string whatIsMyIp = "http://whatismyip.com";
            string getIpRegex = @"(?<=<TITLE>.*)\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*(?=</TITLE>)";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            string requestHtml = "";
            try
            {
                requestHtml = utf8.GetString(wc.DownloadData(whatIsMyIp));
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                // do something with exception
                Console.Write(we.ToString());
            }
            Regex r = new Regex(getIpRegex);
            Match m = r.Match(requestHtml);
            IPAddress externalIp = null;
            if (m.Success)
            {
                externalIp = IPAddress.Parse(m.Value);
            }
            return externalIp;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The code comes from this post http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24692-showing-the-external-ip-address-in-c%23/ .

Comment: They specifically want you to not do that. See the comment in the web source: `<!--Please set your code to scrape your IP from www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp For more info, please see our "Recommended Automation Practices" thread in the Forum.-->`

Which does not require scraping -- because it is simply plain text of the ip!
    
    
Do they even still include the IP in the title?