# Anyone have any suggestions on how I can do server side web tracking with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to put in some place some very basic web tracking for my MVC application. I'd like to do this on the server side and I am wondering if anyone has any knowledge of some simple classes that I could use to help me with this.

I'd like to track the following things:  The User's IP Address, What page they requested, and what country they are from, as well as the DateTime stamp.

Comment: what do you want to track? errors? service calls? do you mean tracing? need a bit more information about this

Comment: Sorry I didn't add enough information. What I would like to track is page requests. Tracking the page requested and the country that it was requested from along with the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can intercept this in the controller for each request:

If you want the page the user requested:

`Request.RawUrl //Gives the current and complete URL the user requested`

If you want the Country it was requested from, you can get the IP address of the user and [then use a ready-made function to look up where it's from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879837/smart-way-to-get-the-public-internet-ip-address-geo-loc):

`Request.UserHostAddress`

You can also get all the route values the user has passed in; to get a more complete picture of how they got to where they are.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        var userIP = Request.UserHostAddress;
        var requestedUrl = Request.UserHostAddress;
        var routeValues = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route.GetRouteData(HttpContext);
        var requestedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Now, you'd have to put this on each action, and that seems silly, so [why not have this happen for everything that's executed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx)?

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuting(
    ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var userIP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
    var requestedUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
    var routeData = ((MvcHandler)filterContext.HttpContext.CurrentHandler).RequestContext.RouteData.Route.GetRouteData(filterContext.HttpContext);
    var requestedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

}
```